# Filltering of Observable data is not working when the filter is done in a function and not with the subscribe action using RxJS

Tags: typescript, filter, rxjs, observable

I am trying to do some filtering of data returned from an external source using the RxJS filter on the Observables.  However, when the code is in a library (function) and not filtered at my UI level, I get all the records returned, not just the records covering the filter.

I have been able to create a simple version to illustrate the issue:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface A {
    name:string;
    age:number;
}

export function Get(Age:number):Observable<A[]> {
    const source:Observable<A[] | null> = of([
      { name: 'Joe', age: 31 }, 
      { name: 'Bob', age: 25 }
    ]);
    console.log(Age)
    return source.pipe(filter( (person, index) => person[index].age >= Age));  
}

const example = Get(30).subscribe(val => {
   val.forEach((OneRecord:A) => {
      console.log(OneRecord)
   })
});
```

This returns both records, even though the filter should only be 1 record.

```
30
>{name: 'Joe', age: 31}
>{name: 'Bob', age: 25}
```

However, if I move the subscribe() and console.log into the function, then the filtering is done correctly. I am not sure why the filter is not limiting what is returned in the observable?

Comment: There's a difference between filtering an *array* and an *observable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter above would have the whole persons array passed in as the first parameter and not each individual person since your observable is streaming an array of people (`Observable<A[]>`).

To filter items out of that list you will need to map the observable values streamed to a new value which will be filtering the non-matching records out of the array:

```js
export function Get(Age:number):Observable<A[]> {
    const source: Observable<A[] | null> = of([
        { name: 'Joe', age: 31 }, 
        { name: 'Bob', age: 25 }
    ]);

    console.log(Age);

    return source.pipe(
        map(people => people.filter(person => person.age >= Age)
    );
}
```